# How to get an <a> tag to respond to onlick in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get two buttons per player that add one or subtract one to their life total and display it on a webpage.

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <TITLE>MTG Life Counter</TITLE>
</head>
<BODY>
    <h1 class = "Head">Magic: The Gathering Life Counter App</h1>
    <p><a href="homepage.html" alt="Back To Home"><img src="logo.png"></a></p>
    <h2>Player 1</h2>
    <div>
        <a class = "button" id = "player1sub">-</a>
        <p id='player1'></p>
        <a class = "button" id = "player1add">+</a>
    <h2>Player 2</h2>
    <div>
        <a class = "button" id = "player2sub">-</a>
        <p id='player2'></p>
        <a class = "button" id = "player2add">+</a>
    </div>
</BODY>
<SCRIPT>
    function sub (life,player){
        life--;
        if (player == 1){
            document.getElementById('player1').innerHTML = player1Life;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('player2').innerHTML = player2Life;
        }
    };
    function add (life,player){
        console.log("AAAAA");
        life++;
        if (player == 1){
            document.getElementById('player1').innerHTML = player1Life;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('player2').innerHTML = player2Life;
        }
    };
    var player1Life = 20;
    var player2Life = 20;
    var p1sub = document.getElementById("player1sub");
    var p1add = document.getElementById("player1add");
    var p2sub = document.getElementById("player2sub");
    var p2add = document.getElementById("player2add");
    p1sub.onclick = sub(player1Life,1);
    p1add.onclick = add(player1Life,1);
    p2sub.onclick = sub(player2Life,2);
    p2add.onclick = add(player2Life,2);

    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('player1').innerHTML = player1Life;
        document.getElementById('player2').innerHTML = player2Life;
    };
</SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

I see the buttons log AAAA in console two times when I load the webpage, but I am assuming that is an initial setup. When I click the button there is not console print and the number does not change.

Comment: `<a class = "button"` — If you want a button, use a `<button>`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> p1sub.onclick = sub(player1Life,1);
> ```

The value you assign to `onclick` has to be a **function**.

Here you are immediately calling the `sub` function and passing its return value to `onclick`.

`sub` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

`undefined` is not a function.

Comment: How should i go about solving this issue? Should I convert the <a> into a button? I would prefer keeping it as an <a> because buttons are a little ugly.

Comment: "How should i go about solving this issue? " — By assigning a function instead.

Comment: "buttons are a little ugly." — That's what CSS is for. It's been around for a couple of decades now.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem would be:

```
p1sub.onclick = function() {sub(player1Life,1);}
p1add.onclick = function() {add(player1Life,1);}
p2sub.onclick = function() {sub(player2Life,2);}
p2add.onclick = function() {add(player2Life,2);}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this solved the issue, I see that the function now works but I do not understand why. Is it because we tell p1sub.onclick to become the function() that then call my function?

Comment: Yes. The value you assign to onclick has to be a function. So your onclick will call that function witch will call your sub() or add() function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want your code do

```js
var player1Life = 20;
var player2Life = 20;
function sub (player){
        if (player == 1){
            player1Life--;
            document.getElementById('player1').innerHTML =             player1Life;
        }
        else {
            player2Life--;
            document.getElementById('player2').innerHTML =              player2Life;
        }
    };
    function add (player){
        if (player == 1){
         player1Life++;
            document.getElementById('player1').innerHTML =              player1Life;
        }
        else {
        player2Life++;
            document.getElementById('player2').innerHTML =              player2Life;
        }
    };
    
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('player1').innerHTML = player1Life;
        document.getElementById('player2').innerHTML = player2Life;
    };
```

```css
.button{
  color:white;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class = "Head">Magic: The Gathering Life Counter App</h1>
    <p><a href="homepage.html" alt="Back To Home"><img src="logo.png"></a></p>
    <h2>Player 1</h2>
    <div>
        <a class = "button" onclick="sub(1);" id ="player1sub">-</a>
        <p id='player1'></p>
        <a class = "button" onclick="add(1);" id ="player1add">+</a>
    <h2>Player 2</h2>
    <div>
        <a class="button" onclick="sub(2);" id="player2sub">-</a>
        <p id='player2'></p>
        <a class="button" onclick="add(2);" id="player2add">+</a>
    </div>
```